# IBM Watson Speech to Text Slow Response TImes

Tags: speech-to-text, ibm-watson

I am using Watson REST API.   The average response time is 5 seconds.    Other STT services I have tested return a response in 1 second.    Is the response time on the production version of Watson faster than 5 seconds?

Comment: Hello, can you please give more details?  When you say it takes 5 seconds to respond, you mean to produce the full hypothesis? or to receive the first interim result? What is the model you are using? Narrowband, Broadband?

Comment: 5 seconds for a full hypothesis on a 5 sec audio file.    I am using Narrowband.    I am using javascript's XMLHttpRequest() object to submit the request and to get a response.

Answer (score -1):

The latency of the Watson STT service is very small, ~1 second or less.
Nothing like trying the Watson STT demo application to get a good feeling of the latency: https://speech-to-text-demo.mybluemix.net/  Just click on "record audio" and start speaking, you will see the words printed in the screen right away.

Comment: How is this an answer?

Comment: The Watson STT demo uses the public API of the Watson STT service. If you speak or feed files through the demo you can measure the latency and real time factor of the Watson STT service.